# Send Reaction to message return Error ANONYMOUS Error

Tags: c#, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

sending Reaction to message in group

```
            Client = new WTelegram.Client(Config2);
            var myself = await Client.LoginUserIfNeeded();
            Console.WriteLine($"We are logged-in as {myself} (id {myself.id})");
            var chats = await Client.Messages_GetAllChats();
            var uuu = chats.chats[1425461922];
            var full = await Client.GetFullChat(uuu);
            var avReactions = (full.full_chat).AvailableReactions as ChatReactionsSome;
            var History = await Client.Messages_GetHistory(uuu);
            foreach (var item in History.Messages)
            {
               Client.Messages_GetAvailableReactions(item.GetHashCode());
                    Reaction reaction = new ReactionEmoji { emoticon =( (avReactions.reactions[(new Random()).Next(0, avReactions.reactions.Count()-1)] as ReactionEmoji).emoticon)}; // all_emoji.reactions.FirstOrDefault().reaction };
                    await Client.Messages_SendReaction(uuu, item.ID, new[] { reaction });

              
            }
```

it return `ANONYMOUS_REACTIONS_DISABLED` error while i am logged in and i dont want to send ANONYMOUS REACTIONS

Answer (score 0):

Check the error list in official documentation:
https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendReaction#possible-errors

> 403   ANONYMOUS_REACTIONS_DISABLED
>
> Sorry, anonymous administrators
> cannot leave reactions or participate in polls.